# Appcelerator/Titanium HTML Chunks/Templates generation

Tags: javascript, templates, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Is there a library like handlebars/dust(can I use it and how?) or smarter way to generate HTML on Appcelerator / Titanium?

Basically I need to populate a HTML template(specifically a table) with data from an array of objects. I would prefer to escape string concatenation as it's ugly and fail-prone. I've searched extensively but couldn't find an answer.

One option that I explored is to load my HTML file into a WebView, create a script inside of it and then use evalJS() of the WebView and pass my data from Titanium to it. However this would require to code another function into the HTML file that manipulates the DOM (which would be a lot of work) and additionally after that I would need to parse it and scrap it off, as  I don't want this part to be visible to the receiver (in case they open the source). ex:

```
var data = [{a:a}, {a:b}, {a:c}];
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({url:'my_template.html'});
var str = "Hello world!";
webview.evalJS("generateTable('"data"');");
```

and then in HTML

```
function generateTable(data) {
//manipulate the DOM to create the table and add the properties...
}
```

Is there some way to utilize chunks/html templating (example):

```
<div class="main">
<table sortable="sortable">
    {% loop in $users as $user %}
        <tr>
            <td class='center'>{$data.id}</td>
            <td class='center'>{$data.date}</td>
            <td class='center'>{$data.name}</td>
            <td class='center'>{$data.email}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endloop %}
</table>
```

Any suggestions/samples would gladly be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've got underscore.js in my project I ended up utilizing the templating in it. It suits my needs as the processing is done in the titanium/appcelerator part of the environment and I don't need to implement communication between it and a WebView (as suggested by Fokke). The HTML is generated and after that it's presented for viewing or/and sharing. Other options that I've looked at:

- Mustache is logic less, so it would've required some extra tweaking
  to generate the HTML.
- Handlebars didn't run in the titanium/appcelerator environment (caused the application to exit when trying to load it. I didn't attempt to utilize it in a WebView

The template part of the regular HTML file is:

```
<div class="main">
    <table sortable="sortable">
        <tr class="hidden">
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
        <% _.each(users, function(user, key, list) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= user.name %></td>
            <td><%= user.address %></td>
            <td><%= user.email %></td>
            <td><%= user.phone %></td>
        </tr>
        <% });%>
    </table>
</div>
```

The javascript portion:

```
_ = require('lib/underscore')._;

var listOfUsers = mdb.fetchAllUsersForExport();

var templateFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, '/templates/template.html');
var mTemplate = templateFile.read();

var render = _.template(mTemplate);
var html = render({
    users : listOfUsers)
});

//use the html in WebView or output it to file for sharing....
```

The listOfUsers is a simple array of objects:

```
  [{name: "John Doe", email: "john.doe@email.com"}, {name: "Jane Doe", email: "jane.doe@email.com", address: "Galaxy 2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

(Almost) Anything you can do in the browser, you can do in a WebView, including using libraries like Handlebars. From the HTML that you load into the WebView you can reference other JavaScript files embedded in your app.

See the [WebView Guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Integrating_Web_Content) for all details.